# Clarification of Notation in MTW's Gravitation, Section 6.4

Tags: general-relativity, conventions, notation

Three difficulties concerning notation in MTW's Gravitation Section 6.4, which introduces a coordinate system for an accelerated frame:

1. > the time axis ***e***<sub>0'</sub> is the observer's 4-velocity, so he is always at rest in this frame; and the other three vectors ***e***<sub>1'</sub> are chosen in such a way as to be (1) orthogonal and (2) nonrotating.

   By "the other three vectors ***e***<sub>1'</sub>" they mean the vectors ***e***<sub>1'</sub>, ***e***<sub>2'</sub> and ***e***<sub>3'</sub>, right?
2. > These basis vectors are:
   >
   >  
   > (*e*<sub>0'</sub>)<sup>*μ*</sup> = (cosh *gτ*; sinh *gτ*, 0, 0);
   > (*e*<sub>1'</sub>)<sup>*μ*</sup> = (sinh *gτ*; cosh *gτ*, 0, 0);
   > (*e*<sub>2'</sub>)<sup>*μ*</sup> = (0; 0, 1, 0);
   > (*e*<sub>3'</sub>)<sup>*μ*</sup> = (0; 0, 0, 1).

   These are actually the *components* of the basis vectors, and not the basis vectors themselves, right? Since the book always stresses the importance of treating vectors and its components as different things, the phrase "These basis vectors are" got me confused.
3. In the above quote, why did they put a semicolon after each first component and a comma after the others, like in (*e*<sub>2'</sub>)<sup>*μ*</sup> = (0; 0, 1, 0)?

Comment: The current formulation of your question is opinion-based, since it asks pretty much what people think a out the book. I suggest editing the question to simply ask the three points you raised without asking whether the book is well written. There *is* reason for them to use those notations, and the main point of your question seems to be to understand these reasons

Comment: I think $\mathbf e_{1’}$ is a typo; they meant $\mathbf e_{i’}$.

Comment: The semicolon is a reminder that the first component is the time component and the others are the space components.